# Why my button is can not set 50%width and separate on each side?

Tags: html, css

```css
#center {
  position: absolute;
  top:35%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index:100;
}

#add_form {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:90%;
  /*height:20em;*/
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
}

#add_form p {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-top:25px;
  padding-right:25px;
  padding-left:25px;
  text-align: left;
}

#userID {
  width:80%;
  height:2em;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border:1px #D3D3D3 solid;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-left:10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

#submitGetCancel, #submitGetCheck {
  width:50%;
  height:3em;
  background-color: red;
  color: #740000;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="center"> 
<div id="add_form">
          <p>Some String</p>
          <input type="text" id="userID" name="userID">
          <!-- <br/> -->
          <div id="buttons">
            <button type="button" id="submitGetCancel" onclick="closeForm();">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" id="submitGetCheck">confirm</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  
  </div>
```

What I want is make 50% width of each button so they will place on each side.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `float:left`

```css
#center {
  position: absolute;
  top:35%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index:100;
}

#add_form {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:90%;
  /*height:20em;*/
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
}

#add_form p {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-top:25px;
  padding-right:25px;
  padding-left:25px;
  text-align: left;
}

#userID {
  width:80%;
  height:2em;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border:1px #D3D3D3 solid;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-left:10px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

#submitGetCancel, #submitGetCheck {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  height:3em;
  background-color: red;
  padding:0;
  color: #740000;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="center"> 
<div id="add_form">
          <p>Some String</p>
          <input type="text" id="userID" name="userID">
          <!-- <br/> -->
          <div id="buttons">
            <button type="button" id="submitGetCancel" onclick="closeForm();">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" id="submitGetCheck">confirm</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline-block;` for button:

```
#submitGetCancel, #submitGetCheck {
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
  height:3em;
  background-color: red;
  padding:0;
  color: #740000;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-style: none;
}
```